# Program exceeds time limit

Tags: c#, .net

this is my first time coming here with a question, please don't beat me up too much.
I'm trying to solve a problem and can't figure out how to optimize it
The program doesn't pass the time limit

I tried to reduce the time to check the row for a number in the range by using the ArraySegment method, but I could not implement it correctly

Time limit: 1 second
Memory limitation: 256 MiB
A virologist experimented on K strains of the virus and recorded the temperatures at which that strain died. The number of experiments on each strain could be different. Let's call the size of the temperature range, which is fatal for all strains of the virus, the difference between the boundaries of the temperature range, which contains at least one temperature to kill each of the strains of the virus. Help the virologist determine the minimum possible size of such a range.

The format of the input data is.

The first line contains a single positive integer K the number of virus strains, 1 <= K <= 10^5 Then k lines containing spaces separated integers. The first number in the i-th row is the number of experiments on the i-th strain which ended in the destruction of the strain, 1 < Mi < 10^5, then Mi, the temperature values in the experiments in which the strain died, all values in the range from -10^7 to 10^7. The total number of experiments performed on all strains does not exceed 10^5.

Output data format

One integer is the minimum possible size of the temperature range that is lethal for all strains of the virus.

Example
Test

3

5 3 9 15 24 20

4 1 9 13 14

4 5 15 12 11

Answer

1

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;


namespace SkuratovAvtomat
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int gr1, gr2;
            int min = Int32.MaxValue;
            int kount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int j;
            int[][] virus = new int [kount][];
            List<int> temp = new List<int>();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < kount; i++)
            {
                List<int> tempp = new List<int>();
                int[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
                virus[i] = input;
                tempp.AddRange(virus[i]);
                tempp.RemoveRange(0,1);
                temp.AddRange(tempp);
            }

            SortedSet<int> sorttemp = new SortedSet<int>(temp);
            temp.Clear();
            temp = sorttemp.ToList();
            int y = temp.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
             {
                 
                 gr1 = temp[i];
                 for (int k = i; k < y; k++)
                 {
                     j = 0;
                     gr2 = temp[k];
                     
                     for (int o = 0; o < kount; o++)
                     {
                         bool prov = false;
                         for (int l = 1; l < virus[o].Length; l++)
                         {
                             if (gr1 <= virus[o][l] & virus[o][l] <= gr2)
                             {
                                 j++;
                                 prov = true;
                                 break;
                             }
                         }
                         if (prov == false)
                             break;
                     }
                     if(j == kount)
                         min = Math.Min(Math.Abs(gr1 - gr2), min);
                 }
             }
             Console.WriteLine(min);
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can find input file that i have problem https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VvC_osh5NM6ww35p9qjarLd3PYHiJB7c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Variable names like temp, tempp, sorttemp, gr1, gr2 and prov make this very hard to read. Can you please explain _what_ you want to achieve with this, _what_ your time limit is and _what_ exactly your problem is besides "it's too slow? Try asking concrete questions like "why does this specific operation take that much time". Hint: Use stopwatches to measure times and identify your problem.

Comment: Hi welcome to the forum. Could you give us some explanation please. What time limit do you have to work to? Where in the program does this time limit apply - I see that there's some console user interaction. What is the aim of the program? Is there one area that we should focus on?